# How to change the variable value used within another variable from the scss mixin

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I tried to change the variable used in another variable from the mixin, but I couldn't change the variable value.

```
$color: white !default;
$var: "this #{$color} is a test" ;

@mixin test($value, $color) {
  // here how to override the $color value
  color: $value;
}

.a {
  @include test($var, #ccc);
}
```

By default the `$color` value is in white, and this `$color` variable is used in another variable `$var`.

When I pass the `$var` inside a mixin to change its variable (`$color`) value, it is not changed. Anyone please suggest the solution for this?

**Expected Output:**

```
.a {
  color: "this #ccc is a test";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the `$var` variable as the argument, its value is not updated because it has already been assigned. Passing a new `$color` variable in the mixin won't update the variable. A workaround can be by using the `set-nth` function to replace the white with the color passed in the mixin:

```
$color: white !default;
$var: #{$color}, red;

@mixin test($value, $colour) {
  // here how to override the $color value
  $var: set-nth($value, 1, $colour);
  color: $var;
}

.a {
  @include test($var, #ccc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update its working for list, but I need it for string. Is it possible? I have modified the code snippet as per the requirement.

Comment: @YahweRaj: I don't think this is possible. In such a case you can manually update the value manually or create a function/mixin which gives an output as per the variable passed as the argument